# How to use "&" in a "spanish-english" document

Tags: biblatex, languages, ampersand

I am writing my thesis in Spanish, but i have 2 chapters in English. What I need is:

Use "&" in all references in both languages.

My problem is that all my chapters (English and Spanish) are using "y" instead of "&"

I'm using `biblatex`:

```
\documentclass[11pt, spanish, singlespacing, headsepline,]{PhDDoctoralThesis} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{palatino} 
\usepackage[maxbibnames=99,backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex} % 
\DefineBibliographyStrings{spanish}{%
andothers        = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot},
andmore          = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot},
}
\addbibresource{/Users/Me/Documents/Bibtex/library.bib}
```

NOTE:
In `myfile.cls` appears `\RequirePackage{babel}` but I'm not using `\usepackage{babel}` in my `main.text`

NOTE2:
I wrote my English chapters by using `\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Chapter}`.

Comment: You also appear to be using `babel`. Is this hunch correct?

Comment: What about all other localisation strings in `biblatex`? Do they need to be English or Spanish? (Assume it matters even if in practice the strings coincide). It would help to see an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/). Because we need to know how you set up your language stuff (`babel`) and how you change the language in the two English chapters.

Comment: I've updated my post with more information. Thank you!

Comment: You mention `myfile.cls` but you load `PhDDoctoralThesis.cls`. There are many versions of that template around. Which do you use exactly?

Comment: Version 1.5 2016/11/22 latextemplate.com

Comment: I could only find 1.6 at latextemplates.com. That version indeed loads `babel`.

Comment: Does `\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}` help?

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: Ah, yes Spanish is ... complicated. Try `\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}
\makeatletter
\DefineBibliographyExtras{spanish}{\restorecommand\lbx@finalnamedelim}
\makeatother`

Comment: I get error: Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ​ (U+200B)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX.

Comment: Just re-type what I wrote in my comment manually. This site sometimes inserts invisible characters in the comments, in this case, there is a zero-width non-joiner and space in `\lbx@final‌​namedelim`.

Comment: Yeees! It worked. Thank you so much for your help! You are the best!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\DeclareDeliFormat{finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}
```

will make the delimiter between the last two names an `&`. But because Spanish is special with 'y' and 'e' you will also need to reset `\lbx@finalnamedelim` with

```
\makeatletter
\DefineBibliographyExtras{spanish}{\restorecommand\lbx@finalnamedelim}
\makeatother
```

*This is an answer for `biblatex` v3.8 and above. See the edit history for an answer for older versions.*